# JSX emoji to string

Tags: javascript, unicode, reactjs, emoji

I'm working on adding emoji support to my JSX React based application.

I have 2 possible options for this:

Either use #1

```
  const stringFromUTF16 = (charCodes) => { return "\uD83D\uDC6E" };
  const EMOJI_UTF16 = {
    "police_officer": [0xD83D, 0xDC6E]
  }
  const EMOJI = _.mapValues(EMOJI_UTF16, stringFromUTF16);
```

or #2

```
  const EMOJI = {
    "police_officer": "\uD83D\uDC6E"
  }
```

In both cases `EMOJI.police_officer =`

Searching the webs, everyone are recommending #1 but option #2 seems by far simpler.

Are there any downsides to #2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the first example really do nothing except returning `{police_officer : "\uD83D\uDC6E"}` (look at your `stringFromUTF16` function), so in your case they are similar.

JSX translator will understand correctly either unicode codes or even unicode symbols (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html), so you do not use any converting functions or tricks.

And if you use ES6 translator, you also absolutely don't need anything like lodash or underscore.